# How to find out if a specific package is installed on Debian?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, dpkg

I'm working with a Raspberry Pi B+ and Raspbian 5/5/2015 and some guides that are a few years old.  I've got an external NTFS HDD hooked up to the Pi.  Due to the articles age(s), common practices have changed, and it turns out that certain packages and features and functions are now built-in and/or automatic.

For example, [I found out that Raspbian will handle the automounting of an NTFS drive/volume](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33625/raspberry-pi-and-read-write-on-ntfs-with-raspbian-5-5-2015/33626#33626) if you just install ntfs-3g.  All instructions and guidance I could find (IRC, raspberry pi forum, and a Linux dude I know) all went extremely technical doing who-knows-what to my system to try to assist me, when in reality we were all tripping over automatic features that no one knew about or thought to check.  I've since installed Raspbian fresh to a new SD card and so far just turned on SSH, updated apt-get,  and installed ntfs-3g.

This is the article I am using right now: http://www.howtogeek.com/139433/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-low-power-network-storage-device/?PageSpeed=noscript

My next step is to get Samba up and running.  Yes, I know Linux people hate Windows, but I'm a Windows guy, so until I can know enough about Linux for a Linux system to be my fallback, Windows machines are my fallbacks.  Eventually this Raspberry Pi will get a multi-TB drive, though for right now it's just a few GB; which is why it needs to be NTFS.

I would like to check if Samba is installed, since the next step in my instructions tell me how to install and configure it.  I've tried a few commands and I'm not sure what to do with the results or how to use them.  I searched here and the technical details are above my capabilities and I don't think they address my seemingly simple need to find out if a package is installed or not.

I tried:

```
apt-cache dump
```

this gave me way too much data.  It scrolled down for a few minutes.  I got this from The Raspberry Pi Handbook 3rd Edition [(Link - Amazon)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3598308264)

I tried

```
apt-cache showpkg samba
Package: samba
Versions:
2:3.6.6-6+deb7u5 (/var/lib/apt/lists/mirrordirector.raspbian.org_raspbian_dists_                                  wheezy_main_binary-armhf_Packages)
 Description Language:
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/mirrordirector.raspbian.org_raspbian_d                                  ists_wheezy_main_binary-armhf_Packages
                  MD5: 0122ac62ef5f4ae21eb2e195eb45ad1d


Reverse Depends:
  winbind,samba 2.2.3-2
  task-file-server,samba
  swat,samba 2:3.6.6-6+deb7u5
  smbclient,samba 2.999+3.0.alpha21-4
  samba4-common-bin,samba 2:3.3.0~rc2-5
  samba4,samba 2:3.3.0~rc2-5
  samba-dbg,samba 2:3.6.6-6+deb7u5
  samba-common-bin,samba 3.0.20b-1
  samba-common,samba 3.0.20b-1
  qtsmbstatus-server,samba
  qemu-system,samba
  nautilus-share,samba 3.0.27a
  libwbclient0,samba 2:3.4.1
  libpam-winbind,samba 2.2.3-2
  libpam-smbpass,samba
  libnss-winbind,samba 2.2.3-2
  gadmin-samba,samba
  education-main-server,samba
  dpsyco-samba,samba
Dependencies:
2:3.6.6-6+deb7u5 - samba-common (5 2:3.6.6-6+deb7u5) libwbclient0 (5 2:3.6.6-6+d                                  eb7u5) libacl1 (2 2.2.51-8) libattr1 (2 1:2.4.46-8) libc6 (2 2.13-28) libcap2 (2                                   2.10) libcomerr2 (2 1.01) libcups2 (2 1.4.0) libgcc1 (2 1:4.4.0) libgssapi-krb5                                  -2 (2 1.10+dfsg~) libk5crypto3 (2 1.6.dfsg.2) libkrb5-3 (2 1.10+dfsg~) libldap-2                                  .4-2 (2 2.4.7) libpam0g (2 0.99.7.1) libpopt0 (2 1.14) libtalloc2 (2 2.0.4~git20                                  101213) libtdb1 (2 1.2.7+git20101214) zlib1g (2 1:1.1.4) debconf (18 0.5) debcon                                  f-2.0 (0 (null)) libpam-runtime (2 1.0.1-11) libpam-modules (0 (null)) lsb-base                                   (2 3.2-13) procps (0 (null)) update-inetd (0 (null)) adduser (0 (null)) dpkg (2                                   1.15.7.2) openbsd-inetd (16 (null)) inet-superserver (0 (null)) smbldap-tools (0                                   (null)) ldb-tools (0 (null)) ctdb (0 (null)) logrotate (0 (null)) tdb-tools (0                                   (null)) samba4 (3 4.0.0~alpha6-2) samba-common (1 2.0.5a-2)
Provides:
2:3.6.6-6+deb7u5 -
Reverse Provides:
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ apt-cache showpkg ntfs-3g
Package: ntfs-3g
Versions:
1:2012.1.15AR.5-2.1+deb7u2 (/var/lib/apt/lists/mirrordirector.raspbian.org_raspbian_dists_wheezy_main_binary-armhf_Packages) (/var/lib/dpkg/status)
 Description Language:
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/mirrordirector.raspbian.org_raspbian_dists_wheezy_main_binary-armhf_Packages
                  MD5: b2df024e8627b5d253b85f35263376ef


Reverse Depends:
  udisks,ntfs-3g
  ntfsprogs,ntfs-3g
  ntfs-config,ntfs-3g
  ntfs-3g-dev,ntfs-3g 1:2012.1.15AR.5-2.1+deb7u2
  ntfs-3g-dbg,ntfs-3g 1:2012.1.15AR.5-2.1+deb7u2
  kvpm,ntfs-3g
  fsarchiver,ntfs-3g
Dependencies:
1:2012.1.15AR.5-2.1+deb7u2 - debconf (18 0.5) debconf-2.0 (0 (null)) libc6 (2 2.13-28) libfuse2 (2 2.8.1) libgcc1 (2 1:4.4.0) libgcrypt11 (2 1.4.5) libgnutls26 (2 2.12.17-0) multiarch-support (0 (null)) fuse (0 (null)) libntfs-3g75 (0 (null)) ntfsprogs (3 1:2011.10.9AR.1-3~) libntfs-3g75 (0 (null)) ntfsprogs (0 (null))
Provides:
1:2012.1.15AR.5-2.1+deb7u2 -
Reverse Provides:
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ apt-cache showpkg ntfsprogs
Package: ntfsprogs
Versions:
1:2012.1.15AR.5-2.1+deb7u2 (/var/lib/apt/lists/mirrordirector.raspbian.org_raspbian_dists_wheezy_main_binary-armhf_Packages)
 Description Language:
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/mirrordirector.raspbian.org_raspbian_dists_wheezy_main_binary-armhf_Packages
                  MD5: 95f41af9cf1d0b5b66afb7d2a9e7c75d


Reverse Depends:
  partitionmanager,ntfsprogs
  ntfs-3g,ntfsprogs
  ntfs-3g,ntfsprogs 1:2011.10.9AR.1-3~
  gparted,ntfsprogs
  fsarchiver,ntfsprogs
  fai-setup-storage,ntfsprogs
Dependencies:
1:2012.1.15AR.5-2.1+deb7u2 - ntfs-3g (0 (null))
Provides:
1:2012.1.15AR.5-2.1+deb7u2 -
Reverse Provides:
```

but I'm not sure what to make of the results.  I can't tell if it's going to apt-get the servers and getting information, or pulling it from my system.

I tried :

```
dpkg --get-selections
```

which I got from here:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/show-the-list-of-installed-packages-on-ubuntu-or-debian/?PageSpeed=noscript
but I think I'm running into the same problem.  It seems the syntax has changed since 2007.  The man page / help file seems to lead me to believe that the command should work

```
Usage: dpkg [<option> ...] <command>

--get-selections [<pattern> ...] Get list of selections to stdout.
```

but I get an error:

```
dpkg –get-selections samba
dpkg: error: need an action option
```

I found a few wuestions here that are related, but don't give me what I am looking for.  I am interested in just knowing what's installed, but I guess that's a topic for another question.

- [What packages are installed by default in Debian? Is there a term for that set? Why some of those packages are `automatically installed` and some not?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90523/what-packages-are-installed-by-default-in-debian-is-there-a-term-for-that-set)
- [How do we know what applications are installed in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113573/how-do-we-know-what-applications-are-installed-in-linux)
- [Loop to check whether a Debian package is installed or not](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180822/loop-to-check-whether-a-debian-package-is-installed-or-not)
- [Determine if a package is provided by an installed packagein Arch Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137295/determine-if-a-package-is-provided-by-an-installed-packagein-arch-linux)

Comment: Are Raspban and Debian interchangeable?  I would think not since Raspbian is specific to the Raspberry Pi and Debian probably can run on multiple hardware platforms.

Comment: Raspbian and Debian are not interchangeable, but Raspbian is a Debian derivative with the same package management mechanisms.  The answers below using commands like apt-cache and dpkg apply equally to both (and to Ubuntu, Linux Mint, etc.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`apt-cache showpkg` shows detailed information about potentially installable packages. It does indicate whether the package is installed, kind of, but not in a very readable way:

```
Versions:
2:3.6.6-6+deb7u5 (/var/lib/apt/lists/mirrordirector.raspbian.org_raspbian_dists_wheezy_main_binary-armhf_Packages)
```

If the package was installed, you'd see `(/var/lib/dpkg/status)` at the end of the line. However, this isn't fully reliable, because you'd also see this indication if the package was known to your system but not fully installed, e.g. if it was in the “package uninstalled but configuration files left over” state.

A more useful `apt-cache` subcommand is `apt-cache policy`. It clearly shows the installed version (if any) and the available version(s). For example, here's output from a machine which has `samba` installed but not `samba-dev`:

```
samba:
  Installed: 2:4.1.17+dfsg-2
  Candidate: 2:4.1.17+dfsg-2
  Version table:
 *** 2:4.1.17+dfsg-2 0
        500 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
samba-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2:4.1.17+dfsg-2
  Version table:
     2:4.1.17+dfsg-2 0
        500 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
```

Alternatively, you can use the `dpkg` command to get information about your current system. APT is the software that manages the download of packages, dependency analysis, etc. Dpkg is the low-level software that carries out the actual installation of a package file.

```
dpkg -l samba
```

This shows a line beginning with `i` if the package is installed, and a line beginning with `u` or `p` or nothing at all if the package is not installed.

```
$ dpkg -l samba samba-dev
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  samba          2:4.1.17+dfs amd64        SMB/CIFS file, print, and login s
dpkg-query: no packages found matching samba-dev
```

(`dpkg-query` is the `dpkg` subcommand that returns information about the package database.)

Note that if you just want to ensure that a package is installed, you can simply run

```
apt-get install samba
```

This won't do anything if the latest version of the package that's available in your distribution is already installed. It will install the package if it isn't installed yet, and it will upgrade it if you have an older version.

Answer (score 6):

```
dpkg -l | grep -e package1 -e package2 ....
```

Will list packages you are interested with their current insstallation stauts. The output will be something like this

```
bala@bala-laptop:~$ dpkg -l | grep apache2
ii  apache2                                2.4.10-10                            amd64        Apache HTTP Server
```

The first 2 characters tell the status - ii here means
First i - marked for installation
Second i - Successfully installed

There are other status codes like r meaning marked for removal, p meaning marked for purging etc.

Comment: +1 for power plus simplicity, and allowing partial matches if you don't know the exact package name.  Partial in that dpkg -l|grep php might return php5, php5-cli, php5-common, etc.

Comment: dpkg -l apache2 | grep '`^ii'

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me

```
dpkg-query -s <pkg>
```

might be simpler than other options.

This command is compatible with script testing, by ignoring the output:

```
dpkg-query -s <pkg> >/dev/null 2>&1
```

and returning 0 if the package is installed, or 1 if it is not installed.

Answer (score 1):

> dpkg -l $PACKAGENAME

is enough. The first two characters in the line will show the package status

Comment: specifically, the status `ii` means it is installed

Answer (score 1):

```
aptitude show foo
```

will show status of the pakage

```
root@srv:# aptitude show python-jmespath
Package: python-jmespath
Version: 0.9.0-2
State: not installed
Priority: optional
Section: python
Maintainer: Debian Python Modules Team python-modules-team@lists.alioth.debian.org
Architecture: all
Uncompressed Size: 97.3 k
Depends: python (>= 2.7)
Description: JSON Matching Expressions (Python 2)
 JMESPath is python library which allows you to declaratively specify how to extract elements from a JSON document.

 This package contains the module for Python 2.
Homepage: https://github.com/boto/jmespath


root@cx-ops02:#
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly simpler alt to `dpkg -l | grep  ...` IMO:

```
dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}' pkg | grep -q " installed"
```

Will return 0 (success) iff `pkg` is installed.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep-status 'package'
```

It is not preinstalled in Debian based distro. It can be installed through:

```
sudo apt install dctrl-tools
```

Here is an example:

```
$ grep-status dctrl-tools

Package: dctrl-tools
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: utils
Installed-Size: 296
...
```

[grep-status manpages](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/dctrl-tools/grep-status.1.en.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've previously used `dpkg-query`, which enabled testing of multiple packages in one invocation.

Using Bash (for array variables):

```bsh
REQUIRED_TOOLS=(gnupg libcdio-utils python-apt realpath syslinux wget)
MISSING_TOOLS=$(dpkg-query -Wf'${db:Status-Abbrev}${binary:Package}\n' "${REQUIRED_TOOLS[@]}" 2>&1 | sed -n 's/.* no packages found matching /n/;s/^[^i]//p') | xargs echo

ERRORS="${MISSING_TOOLS:+Missing tools - please install: $MISSING_TOOLS}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Over the years the syntax of `apt` got a lot simpler.

Now you can just use `apt list <packagename>`

Answer (score -1):

I hope you can solve this problem.

- `dpkg --help` for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
- use `apt` or `aptitude` for user-friendly package management;
- type `dpkg -Dhelp` for a list of `dpkg` debug flag values;
- type `dpkg --force-help` for a list of forcing options;
- type `dpkg-deb --help` for help about manipulating `*.deb` files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through `less` or `more` !