# Prevent apt list from throwing error

Tags: linux, command-line, apt

I'm trying to detect if a package is installed in a bash script using the following but the script keeps erroring out and preventing anything after it from running.

Is there an option for `apt` that tells it to NOT throw an error when a package is not in the list?

```
pkgExists=$(apt list "azure-cli" | grep "azure-cli" -s)
```

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [How to find out if a specific package is installed on Debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/217076/86440) (I can’t start a vote...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a package is not in the list, `apt list` just shows `Listing... Done` and exits. If you try to pipe its output like you do however it throws a clear warning:

> WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Use `dpkg-query --list` instead, e.g.:

```
dpkg-query --list "azure-cli" && echo "exists" || echo "doesn't exist"
```

Note that `dpkg-query --list` doesn’t show packages that are not installed.